# Calculate $\sup\limits_{x\in(0,+\infty)}\frac{x^2 e^{-n/x}}{n^2+x^2}$

Tags: sequences-and-series, supremum-and-infimum

Calculate
$$\sup_{x\in(0,+\infty)}\frac{x^2 e^{-n/x}}{n^2+x^2}$$
The derivative is
$$\frac{n e^{-n/x} (n+x)^2}{(n^2+x^2)^2}\geq 0$$
then
$$\sup_{x\in(0,+\infty)}\frac{x^2 e^{-n/x}}{n^2+x^2}=\lim_{x\rightarrow +\infty}\frac{x^2 e^{-n/x}}{n^2+x^2}=1$$
I would get the same result without using the derivative. We welcome suggestions.

Comment: It doest not go infinity as x goes infinity. $$\lim_{x\rightarrow +\infty}\frac{x^2 e^{-n/x}}{n^2+x^2}=1$$ $$\lim_{x\rightarrow +0}\frac{x^2 e^{-n/x}}{n^2+x^2}=0,\ \  \forall n \ne 0$$

Comment: Thank you, I corrected my post.

Comment: "without using the derivative" One wants to show that, for every $x>0$, $$\frac{x^2 e^{-n/x}}{n^2+x^2}<1,$$ but this follows from $$\frac{x^2}{n^2+x^2}<1,\qquad e^{-n/x}\leqslant1.$$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For $x\gt0$,
$$
\frac{x^2 e^{-n/x}}{n^2+x^2}
=\frac{e^{-n/x}}{(n/x)^2+1}\tag{1}
$$
Both $e^{-t}$ and $\frac1{t^2+1}$ are positive, monotonically decreasing functions for $t\ge0$. Thus, their product is also a positive, monotonically decreasing function. Therefore, $(1)$ increases as $n/x$ decreases. So, the supremum of $(1)$ would be
$$
\lim_{t\to0}\frac{e^{-t}}{t^2+1}=1\tag{2}
$$
since that function is continuous at $t=0$.

Answer (score 0):

Your function can be written as

$$f(x)=\left(1-\frac{n^2}{n^2+x^2}\right)e^{-n/x}\implies f'(x)=e^{-n/x}\left(\frac{2n^2x}{(n^2+x^2)^2}+\frac n{x^2}\left(1-\frac{n^2}{n^2+x^2}\right)\right)=$$

$$=e^{-n/x}\left(\frac{2n^2x}{(n^2+x^2)^2}+\frac n{n^2+x^2}\right)\ge 0$$

and the function is monotone increasing. Also

$$\lim_{x\to 0^+}f(x)=0\cdot 0=0\;,\;\;\lim_{x\to\infty}f(x)=1\cdot e^0=1$$

and thus the wanted supremum is $\;1\;$ ( assuming $\;n\in\Bbb N\;$)

Comment: "without using the derivative", they said.

Comment: @Did They said "I get the same result without the derivative", *not* "do not use derivatives" . I thought that seeing what's going on the extreme points of the definition itnerval is what they want/need.

Comment: **WOULD**... :-)

Comment: @Did Yes...how is that equal to "do not use derivatives", or to "how would I do this without derivatives"? Perhaps I'm missing some subtle language thing here.